# What pixel per foot ratio renders most efficiently in HTML5 3d-tranform based sims?

Tags: javascript, css, html, 3d

My issue is uncommon and, I think, requires some background in order to adequately phrase the question, so here goes...

I have a 3d world engine similar to [Kieth Clarks'](http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/creating-3d-worlds-with-html-and-css/), only without all the cool lighting effects.  Instead I have some other immersive 3d perks that are also expensive, and chose to fake the lighting for now in order to be able to have the most complexity possible on mobile without dropping many frames noticeably.

I have an approximate visual/spacial scale ratio (not talking transform scales) of css pixels to object size.  For instance, 50px is about 5 feet.  Note, I am not trying to model exact dimensions in the real world, just close enough to be fairly convincing.  Anyway, this means large objects are generally built from tile elements 100px^2.  So a really simple 1-car garage, small hut etc. is easily modeled as a 100px cube made of divs or whatever you want.  Usually I put the walls and top divs inside the bottom div, positioned so it acts as a base, eliminating the need for an extra containing element.

Now, tiles can be any 2d px ratio, but I'm using 100px^2 for big tile css classes, 66px, 50px, 20px, 10px etc. for smaller tile classes to make the markup simpler and easier to change px "scales" in "the world" through the css sheet, or later during runtime style alterations.

It takes *a lot* of tiles to model complex objects.  Obvi, the potential drain on framerate stacks up exponentially as you add in objects, animations, especially large ones or complex shapes like cylinders or spheres (ouch) and have a populated simulation environment, especially outside or anywhere you can see a lot of things at one time.

I have completely re-written this thing three times to accommodate some major changes, using different "physical scale" ratios.  Once enough complexity was achieved, it became apparent there is a huge difference in rendering efficiency when using a different ratio of pixels to feet (or meters, 3 feet being close enough).  Basically it works out pixels/foot but it's important to note the basic tile size is just a little bigger than a 1-car garage door.

This difference is not as obvious as it would seem, such as more pixels more gpu.  Some experiments proved to be more efficient with 100px : 10ft (what I'm using now) as opposed to 50px : 10ft, which is what I used on the first version.

The second version of the engine is a lot more efficient than the first and third, and not just for this reason.  There are different effects involved, and special features that are now central to the purpose of this thing, so it is really time-consuming to play with how many pixels everything is made of.

For the engine to work properly I have to heavily account for various aspects such as css perspective, perspective-origin, altitude and distance of the carousel, and a lot of physical perspective cues that don't have directly-correlating css or DOM attributes, and don't easily translate into numbers I can just swap out using an equation.  Also, changing one of these can wreak havok on proper rendering if you're not careful, of course like flashing, visual super-position, apparent z-order (not real z-order) incorrect etc., or just making the visual perspective look "wierd", even if it's more efficient then and not dropping frames, so making this kind of change is a real hassle and takes a lot of time and page reloads to get it right.

Now my question is this:

***What is the ideal size ratio of pixels to feet for performance?*** I've even tried really small, like 1px is the size of a car and different transform scales for the stage to make it look right.  I can glean a little more efficiency that way, but it throws my numbers for the physics way out of whack, even when I adjust them I'm not quite happy with how things move.  Almost like if you miniaturized yourself to the size of a spider, you and things your relative size would behave a lot differently than they do now.

Should I go small and zoom in?  Should I use larger image tiles and transform:scale3d the whole stage down?  Or should I just use small images and tile elements?  Should I use div's for the tiles, or is one of the newer semantic tags more efficient at rendering in css 3d space?

A combination of the above seems to be more efficient, but it's not a straight line.  Almost like harmonics.  Theres a periodicity to it.  On the small to large pixels/foot ratio continuum, some smaller sizes seem to be *less* efficient than some larger ones.

There's a demo that tests how many cubes your browser can render efficiently, but I wonder if anyone's published results that describe different tile or cube pixel sizes with masses of cubes, or if anyone here has tried something like this.

Addendum: This is primarily geared for Chrome Android as an instant app or embedded in a webview, though hopefully Firefox catches up soon as it can't handle as many cubes.  I will love that.

Couple screenshots of a test space... Note the sky is round.  This is the anaglyph view, which takes the most processing.  The SBS views are a lot more efficient as they use half or less of the viewport, and thereby have less to render since the view for each eye is half the width of anaglyph. 
Also the overhead from mixing the anaglyph views.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Why are you not using OpenGL (WebGl/HTML5 canvas)?

Comment: I suggest using WebGL instead of CSS transforms for 2 reasons: performance, and knowledge-base. WebGL API allows you to directly access the graphics pipeline, where using CSS does not. Also, knowledge of CSS transformations is limited to only those who have 3d modelling experience and have _specific and specialized_ knowledge of HTML and CSS. WebGL does not have that limitation, because it is based on OpenGL, which is a graphics library written for _many languages_

Comment: Using standard markup for parts means a lot of existing things can be translated into 3d objects and embedded in the 3d virtual space.  Theoretically, you could embed a webgl-powered canvas within it.   HTML, SVG, iframes.  Even input elements.  Using a single requestAnimationFrame updating the transforms from a json object seems to make it pretty fast.  I'm running dual-perspective views though.  One of the 3d modes uses the entire viewport for each eye's perspective, so that one slows down a little on my phone sometimes.

Comment: Yes.  WebGL is pretty awesome in those ways.  I think there might be a different set of advantages though for using translations.  It's getting a lot more efficient as browser updates come along, not to mention faster devices.  On a laptop you can really load it down without a blink, but you don't have device-orientation control.

Comment: There was a post sometime not too long ago that talked about when you should use CSS and when you should use WebGL. I can not remember where I found it, but it said for modelling purposes a WebGL canvas would do better. If you are making an interface, or making interface content (like inputs, forms, textboxes, etc) transforms are better. It looks like you are modelling though, even if there are animations.

Comment: Oh, yes.  I absolutely agree, if you want fluid models with lots of polygons, especially triangles as we all know those are the basic building-blocks (block?) for anything curvy along two axes (such as a sphere), and it's more optimized atthis point in time.  You can indeed import webgl objects into a canvas in my environment.  You just have to add a class to the canvas that makes the canvas always face the camera, and have the objects logic dictate it's relative rotation, animations etc.  Probably what I will use for avatars.  This thing is actually a 3d ssh terminal..

Comment: allowing you to work in a shared environment.  It is really flexible.  There are plans with w3c and the powers that be to implement other shapes soon, besides just rectangles and circles, into html5.  Hardware and software optimization just keep moving forward.  I've seen some really beautiful 3d web enviroments you would never guess aren't webgl.  Very intricate, very curvy.  Anyway, I think with all I've read and seen, and the experimentation I've done, this is gonna be a thing.  And defininitely it works great for interfaces.  2d, 3d SBS/TB, VR, anaglyph.  I've got lots of viewing choices.

Comment: @DaMaxContent, I added a couple screenshots, though this is not my best looking test-space.  I still have to "port" the really nice ones over to the new setup, but will probably wait till it's integrated with the server so I can just load them and and alter on-the-fly.

Comment: Sorry, I have been fairly inactive (I'm not an avid S.E. user anymore). The reason I brought up WebGL, is because I am not too specialized in 3d transforms (not that couldn't figure out a solution, just too lazy to go through and learn the reqs for such an answer) and I am not too specialized in 3d transforms for those reasons I had mention. Sorry, I am not much help mate :/

Comment: No worries!  I appreciate the input.  ;)  I don't know WebGL too great either.  But when I ran across Kieth Clark's FPS demo I was awe-inspired.  I found another post where a guy made a little VR setup using transforms to view a cube, and one using blend-modes to make an anaglyph photo, and thought "I could do this! (maybe?)"  So I did.  Anyway, another idea for this is being able to view actual web-pages in differnt VR and 3D modes without exiting the viewer or taking off the goggles.  Like a 3D web..  Probably have to splice into into a real app.

Comment: @DaMaxContent-- Here's a link to some vid's I me a while back of the different viewing modes, including regular single-display.  Quality on real thing is a lot better though.  My Virtual Reality: http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLE1kreMb4-EJIt5MoAgTgP6Ovj4SrMtOW